# Running a PHP script located on FTP server

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

So I have a php script that connects to a MySQL database that runs fine on my server and my schools server when it is ran. I currently have to have my script connect to another database but get the following error

```
Host "host" is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I did search and found the option to use `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES "."` for the user but wanted to know if it is possible (Since I have to submit these files to the persons FTP) to run it after I upload the file to the ftp server. My guess is where the database is located as well. HTML runs fine off the ftp but when I try to open the php script All I see is just the code instead of anything running. Is it impossible to run a PHP script off the ftp using `ftp://ftpserver/script.php`?

Or am I looking at this the wrong way?
I apologize for any beginner annoyance as I've never really worked with FTP and how they function when it comes to this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You've got a few problems - if all you see is code when you look at your PHP script, then you should start with ensuring that PHP is installed and configured properly on this 3rd server (the one that isn't yours your school's - that's where the problem is, no?)

Comment: PHP isn't configured properly on the server. Do you know what Web Server software the "ftpserver" is running on? Is it Apache or IIS or Nginx? Contact the Systems Admin if you don't know

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies, I am awaiting a reply from the admins if all that is configured properly on their side. I may have assumed they had it set up already.